# Object reference is required for a non-static field

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

So I have a nested class - PeerReviews. I am trying to create a listbox on an ASPX page, and I am instantiating an object of PeerReviews like so:

```
PeerReviews obj = new PeerReviews();
```

However, I'm getting an error that this line is causing problems in my code:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(r["first_name"], r["first_name"]));
```

Here's the full code of the nested class:

```
class PeerReviews
        {
            private static void PeerReview()
            {


                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=hourtracking;uid=username;password=password");
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select first_name from employee where active_status=1", con);
                con.Open();
                MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (r.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(r["first_name"], r["first_name"]));
                }
                con.Close();


            }
        }
```

How do I reference the listbox item? I tried to instantiate it as an object (which didn't seem right).

I'm only so-so with OOP programming (I've done some of it, but one of the reasons I'm working in C# is to force myself to use it) and I'm still almost a complete newbie to C# and ASP.NET

EDIT:

This is the ASPX code:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="listBox1" runat="server">
</asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: is listBox1 set as runat="server" in the asp side code?

Comment: I don't think it's that line - check again

Comment: You've also got a memory leak, you need to wrap your connection, command, and reader objects in a `using` statement.

Comment: wait! where is listBox1 declared?

Comment: We need to see the code that calls your PeerReview method. But aside from that, this design seems a little inside out. Try having the nested class return the first name data in a collection, and let the calling code add it to the ListBox.

Comment: I'm still wondering how he was able to access the listbox1 object in the PeerReviews class. Aren't you supposed to be in the page class to do that? and to which class did you "nest" the PeerReviews class?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to remove the `static` keyword on the `PeerReview` function.

Comment: Then this happens:

Compiler Error Message: CS0038: Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'commenter' via nested type 'commenter.PeerReviews'

Comment: Would that mean I just need to instantiate an object of PeerReviews?

Answer (score 0):

Pass reference to object which has listbox1 to static PeerReview method. Static method of class can not access none static fields/properties/methods of its class or any other class. it can only access other static class fields/properties/methods, local variables and arguments

you need something like(I'm not sure instance of System.Web.UI.Page holds listBox1, but I'm questing)

```
private static void PeerReview(System.Web.UI.Page page)
{
//...
page.listBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(r["first_name"], r["first_name"]));
//...
}
```

or as Rawling sayed:

```
    private static void PeerReview(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox listbox)
    {
    //...
    listbox.Items.Add(new ListItem(r["first_name"], r["first_name"]));
    //...
    }
```

Comment: It'll have to be of the type of whatever the current page is. Or you could page the listbox itself instead.